# Generating PPT using Apache POI in Grails application

Tags: grails, apache-poi

I am trying to add apache poi into my grails web application to generate PPT. I dont seem to get the application to compile and I always see the following error.

`Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.apache.poi:poi:zip:3.14 in grailsCentral`

This error is seen only when I include the following line under plugin section of BuildConfig.groovy.

`compile "org.apache.poi:poi:3.14"`

I have included POI jar (as shown below) in the dependency section of BuildConfig and it does not barf at this point.

`compile org.apache.poi:poi:3.14`

Please note that I have added the following to the repository section of BuildConfig too.

`mavenRepo "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi"`

The classes I am trying to import are in the POI jar that I am adding as dependency in my project. However there's an eclipse marker at the line of the import.

What am I missing? Can someone let me know please?

Comment: I don't know a lot about Grails, but in Gradle builds you usually specify the Maven repos as `mavenCentral()`. The URL that you use is the search-result, so likely that one should be stated differently or you may also try removing specifying the repository completely and by this use the default of `mavenCentral()`.

Comment: See [the Apache POI Groovy + Gradle example](http://poi.apache.org/poi-jvm-languages.html#Groovy+example) for a bit more of what you should need - Grails should want something very similar being built on the two!

Comment: Thanks for the response guys! I already have mavenCentral() as one of my repositories and since the dependency was not found there, I had to add an external mavenRepo. But that seems to be making no difference.

Comment: what about 3.13   compile('org.apache.poi:poi:3.13')
This had been working fine for me. You need to add it under dependency block and not under plugins (old grails <3 )? you can also disable the mavenRepo. On new it should be in the same gradle segment that you do rest of plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys. I added 3.13 as a dependency. Somehow, my application still barfed. I had to add few more dependencies. Here's everything I added.

```
compile "org.apache.poi:poi:3.13"
compile "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.13"
compile "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:3.13"
compile "org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:1.1"
```

Answer (score -1):

On grails 2 BuildConfig:

```
 dependencies {
        // compile('org.apache.poi:poi:3.13')
    }
 plugins {
 ///...
}
```

Comment: What's supposed to go in the `plugins` section? Dislike.

Comment: @PrintlnParams unsure why you have downvoted a valid answer. Is this a grails plugin yes no if no then why would any declaration be needed in the plugins section which relates to grails specific plugin declaration???

Comment: It does specifically say grails 2. If you are trying it on grails 3 it will be more like this which can be under plugins . https://github.com/vahidhedayati/test-queuekit3/blob/master/build.gradle line 74